# Finding differences between 2 dictionaries

Tags: c#

I have 2 dictionaries that contain employee information form 2 DB tables in SAP Business 1. They have employee IDs and salaries e.g. I have ensured that the employee IDs of the 1st and 2nd table will always be the same

```
Table 1 (OHEM)

empID    salary
1        40000
2        56000
3        77000
4        80000 <------increase  


Table 2 (Salary Fitment)

empID    salary
1        40000
2        56000
3        77000
4        50000
```

In the above example, if employee number 4 gets an increase/decrease (or any other employee salary change in OHEM), I would like to compare two dictionaries and then update
the corresponding salary in table two.

Code

```
// Get service instances
var employeeService = Program.Kernel.Get<IEmployeeService>();
var salaryFitmentService = Program.Kernel.Get<ISalaryFitmentService>(); 

var OHEMDictionary = employeeService.GetAllEmployees().OrderBy(es => es.empID)
                                 .ToDictionary(od => od.empID,
                                               od => od.salary);

var SalaryFitmentDictionary = salaryFitmentService.GetAllSalaryFitments().Where(x => x.U_PD_Code.Trim().ToString() == "SYS001").OrderBy(es => es.U_Employee_ID)
                                          .ToDictionary(od => od.U_Employee_ID,
                                                              od => od.U_PD_Amount);
```

I already have an update code. What would be the best way to get the dictionary differences so that I could update the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var diff = SalaryFitmentDictionary.Where(kv=>OHEMDictionary[kv.Key]!=kv.Value)
```

**EDIT**

You can also append to get the difference for each employee

```
.Select(kv => new { ID = kv.Key, Amount = OHEMDictionary[kv.Key] - kv.Value })
```

Comment: @naveen, you are correct but this `OHEMDictionary = employeeService.GetAllEmployees` makes me think that OHEMDictionary contains all employees.

Comment: Nice and simple, I just inverted the dictionaries OHEMDictionary.Where(kv => SalaryFitmentDictionary[kv.Key] != kv.Value); and can get the empIDs and new salaries to update.

Answer (score 2):

This is a straight forward but handy function:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> DiffDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> first, Dictionary<string, string> second)
{
    var diff = first.ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => "removed");
    foreach (var other in second)
    {
        string firstValue;
        if (first.TryGetValue(other.Key, out firstValue))
        {
            diff[other.Key] = firstValue.Equals(other.Value) ? "same" : "different";
        }
        else
        {
            diff[other.Key] = "added";
        }
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Especially if you just want to report the type of change:

```
var first = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "one", "two" }, { "three", "four" }, { "five", "six" } };
var second = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "one", "2" }, { "five", "six" }, { "seven", "eight" } };

foreach (var entry in DiffDictionary(first, second))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", entry.Key, entry.Value);
}
```

Which gives

```
one different
three removed
five same
seven added
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information to cover all bases (for example: are the keys in one dictionary a strict subset of those on the other? or maybe both dictionaries have exactly the same number and values of keys?), but generally this is what we 're talking about:

```
foreach(var pair in SalaryFitmentDictionary)
{
    if(OHEMDictionary[pair.Key] != pair.Value)
    {
        // This employee's salary has changed
        OHEMDictionary[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class to contain the differences:

```
public class DictionaryDifference<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TKey Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TValue OriginalValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TValue NewValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Create an extension method to find the differences:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DictionaryDifference<TKey, TValue>> GetDifferencesFrom<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> original,
        IDictionary<TKey, TValue> latest)
        where TValue : IComparable
    {
        foreach (var originalItem in original)
        {
            if (latest.ContainsKey(originalItem.Key))
            {
                if (originalItem.Value.CompareTo(latest[originalItem.Key]) != 0)
                {
                    // The key is in the latest but the value is different.
                    yield return new DictionaryDifference<TKey, TValue>
                    {
                        Key = originalItem.Key,
                        OriginalValue = originalItem.Value,
                        NewValue = latest[originalItem.Key]
                    };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The key is not in the latest dictionary.
                yield return new DictionaryDifference<TKey, TValue>
                {
                    Key = originalItem.Key,
                    OriginalValue = originalItem.Value,
                    NewValue = default(TValue)
                };
            }
        }

        foreach (var newItem in latest)
        {
            if (!original.ContainsKey(newItem.Key))
            {
                // The key is not in the original dictionary.
                yield return new DictionaryDifference<TKey, TValue>
                {
                    Key = newItem.Key,
                    OriginalValue = default(TValue),
                    NewValue = latest[newItem.Key]
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create 2 dictionaries and compare:

```
var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<int, double>();
dictionary1.Add(1, 40000);
dictionary1.Add(2, 56000);
dictionary1.Add(3, 77000);
dictionary1.Add(4, 80000);
dictionary1.Add(5, 100000);

var dictionary2 = new Dictionary<int, double>();
dictionary2.Add(1, 40000);
dictionary2.Add(2, 56000);
dictionary2.Add(3, 77000);
dictionary2.Add(4, 50000);
dictionary2.Add(6, 35000);

foreach (var difference in dictionary1.GetDifferencesFrom(dictionary2))
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Key {0} was {1} but is now {2}",
        difference.Key.ToString(),
        difference.OriginalValue.ToString(),
        difference.NewValue.ToString());
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Key 4 was 80000 but is now 50000
Key 5 was 100000 but is now 0
Key 6 was 0 but is now 35000
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot.  I've changed the foreach loop in my implementation to take care of null old/new differences

Answer (score 0):

```
   var result = from o in OHEMDictionary
                 join f in SalaryFitmentDictionary on o.Key equals f.Key
                 where o.Value != f.Value
                 select { o.Key, o.Value - f.Value};
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only cover those items that appear in both dictionaries, but you could do something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> first = new Dictionary<int, string> 
       { { 1, "One" }, { 2, "Two" }, { 3, "Three" } };
Dictionary<int, string> second = new Dictionary<int, string> 
       { { 1, "One" }, { 2, "Two" }, { 3, "Tri" } };

var difference = from f in first
                 join s in second on f.Key equals s.Key
                 where f.Value != s.Value
                 select new {Key = f.Key, 
                             FirstValue = f.Value, 
                             SecondValue = s.Value };

foreach (var item in difference)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Different item with key {0}, Values {1} and {2}", 
                          item.Key, item.FirstValue, item.SecondValue);
}
```